# Why is my menu not ordered properly?

Tags: menus, themes, screen-layout

I am using the [Avant](https://wordpress.org/themes/avant/) theme, but I don't know if this is a fault of the theme or of WP. My main menu looks like below in the WP designer, with `Home` the first menu item.

[image]

Yet when I visit the blog, the menu appears as below:

[image]

Is this something I can fix? If so, is a child theme the recommended route if this is the theme's fault? Then I can meddle with the header code.

Comment: Did you assign this menu to some menu location at "Manage Locations" tab?

Comment: @motivast No, I didn't even know about that, but it has solved the problem. Why don't you answer so I can accept, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign your new menu to some menu location at "Manage Locations" tab. If you would not do it your pages will be displayed using `wp_page_menu` function which will order your pages by `post_title`.